# 8-bit VGA DAC Design Question

Tags: analog, circuit-design, dac, video, vga

I am being driven up the wall with designing an 8-bit VGA DAC for an embedded application.

Everywhere I've researched highlights the necessity for "impedance matching" the 75 ohm termination resistance of VGA monitors, yet I've seen myriad solutions such as this:

[image]

this:

[image]

this:

[image]

and most commonly this:

[image]

Yet none of these as far as I can tell come anywhere close to impedance matching.

[This thread from this very website](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367797/resistor-dac-and-buffer-for-vga-output) lead me to implement the circuit depicted here:

[image]

Yet this circuit caps my outputs at .63 volts as opposed to the standard's .7 volts, resulting in a noticeable darkness in colors.

So, at this point, I'm at a complete loss as to how to get a 0V-.7V 3-bit weighted or R2R DAC which outputs accurate values given a 75 ohm termination resistance. Because apparently, with the tons of other solutions out there, no one else has a single answer either.

Comment: Does your research include using pen and paper and calculator to find the values yourself or have you just looked how others did it? Like you said yourself, the impedance of a terminated 75 ohm input is quite low for digital chips to drive, so many digital chips have so much output impedance they can't provide full voltage with ideally calculated resistances. And resistor values depend on supply voltage, do you have 5V or 3.3V? A buffer could be used. Light output versus voltage is not linear either due to monitor gamma, so do you even want equal voltage steps but equal brightness steps?

Comment: Yes I attempted the math myself, which resulted in the final schematic I mention. 

How exactly do you mean that 75 ohms is "quite low to drive"? The output itself is 3.3 volts, and all the above examples also claim to use 3.3 volts. How precisely though would a buffer help?

I would argue though that in terms of light vs gamma, I want what is specified by the VGA specification: linear stepping of voltage affecting the RGB inputs resulting in specific brightness.

Comment: U=I*R => I=U/R, so in your case I=3.3/75=0.044A=44mA. Your buffer must drive at least 44mA.

Comment: Why can't you get a larger voltage - by reducing R20..25 and increasing R26 a bit?  Then, If it helps, you probably don't need to stick exactly to a 75 ohm source impedance. Going lower or higher could cause reflections leading to ghosting, but a) if the display end of the cable presents the correct impedance then the source impedance doesn't matter so much, and b) this probably isn't a 4K HDR display. With a short cable the ghosting will be minimal.

Comment: Here is a [very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367797/resistor-dac-and-buffer-for-vga-output) with a wall of text answer. In that answer, the important part is the R2R ladder with the values of 309Ω,618Ω and a pull-down resistor at the output of 99Ω.

Comment: @HarrySvensson This is the exact circuit I'm already using, and the same one that's giving my an almost .1V error.

Comment: @ConnorSpangler In that case the problem is not with the resistors, but with the transistors at the output. They sound weak. Maybe having some kind of buffer would help, or just a very basic logical inverter and invert the bits in software. - If you still want to solve it with your weak transistors then you would have to measure *how* weak they are and change the values of the resistors accordingly. - It's not impossible, if they are weaker when sourcing current compared to sinking current then... you're in bad shape. - But since the VGA cable is terminated at both ends it's very forgiving.

Comment: @ufok OK very interesting! According to my microcontroller datasheet, the pins can only source or sink 40 mA @ 3.3V. Would this 4 mA deficit be enough to contribute noticeably to the error?

Comment: You have 0.63V insteed of 0.70V.  0.63/0.70=0.90. Do same calculation for current: 40mA/44mA=0.91. Results are quite similar ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The first circuit's output impedance is only ~61Ω which is a little low, but the main problem is the maximum output voltage is only ~0.343V when it should be 0.7V.

The second/third circuit is ~77Ω and 0.8V (assuming low impedance 3.3V digital inputs) so it should be OK.

The fourth circuit is ~290Ω and 0.68V. The impedance mismatch will cause reflections, but they will probably be too small to notice if the VGA cable is short. This scheme has the lowest loading while still producing full analog voltages.

If your digital outputs have significant impedance then you should subtract this value from the DAC resistors to get the correct total. However with only 3 bits the error has to be quite large to be noticeable.

Precise impedance matching isn't nexessary, but getting the correct voltage levels is. That means the 75Ω termination must be taken into account when calculating the required resistor values.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown - I must have been miscalculating the impedances, because my results were at least an order of magnitude off. Allegedly the I/O on the microcontroller I'm using have an internal resistance of ~25 ohms; would this be enough to cause the better part of 0.1V error? Also, w/ 75 ohm load being driven, 44 mA is required @ 3.3V. However, according to my microcontroller datasheet, the pins can only source or sink 40 mA @ 3.3V. Would this 4 mA deficit be enough to contribute noticeably to the error?

Comment: 25 Ohms should only reduce peak voltage by ~50mV. But the bigger problem is you haven't taken into account the 75 Ohm termination, which halves the output voltage.Change the DAC ladder resistor values from 619 to 309 and 309 to 154. Also change R26 and R33 from 100 to 180, and R36 from 130 to 160 (adjust these to fine tune the output voltage if necessary).

Comment: The maximum current draw on a single pin is ~10mA on Blue1. Total current draw on all pins is 32mA.